# Criando/Visualizando relatório em HTML

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2

Galera, estou com um problema e não consegui raciocinar uma solução ... Pessoal que já usou iReport sabe que tem como fazer agrupamento de forma bem fácil nele... O problema é que agora estou fazendo relatórios em HTML ( na unha rs ), e queria fazer agrupamento por filiais ( como exemplo ):

```
Filial  001 - LOJA TAL
                              column         column          column         column        column
                              dados           dados            dados           dados          dados
                              dados           dados            dados           dados          dados 
                              dados           dados            dados           dados          dados
Total da Filial 001  =        TOTAL          TOTAL           TOTAL          TOTAL         TOTAL

Filial  002 - LOJA TAL
                              column         column          column         column        column
                              dados           dados            dados           dados          dados
                              dados           dados            dados           dados          dados 
                              dados           dados            dados           dados          dados
Total da Filial 002  =        TOTAL          TOTAL           TOTAL          TOTAL         TOTAL

Total Geral           =       TOTAL GERAL
```

E assim por diante.. no iReport é só colocar um group... Mas agora que to fazendo em HTML, não consigo achar uma solução para meu problema... Pois está repetindo o nome da filial em todas as linhas, e não consegui pensar em como fazer o total para filial e depois o total Geral...

Exemplo :

Digamos que vem os números(resultado da consulta) (1, 1 , 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,) Printar apenas : 1, 2 , 3.

Já tentei pegar os valores da tabela de filiais e comparar com o resultado de filiais que está vindo da consulta, mas não deu certo, continua printando repetidamente.

Por exemplo :

```
 $filias => $this->find(filiais)
 $dadosConsulta['numero_filial'] (este aqui que está vindo repetido, filial para cada resultado)

 if($filiais['numero_filial'] == $dadosConsulta['numero_filial']){
 echo $dadosConsulta['numero_filial'];
 }
```

Tentei algo desse tipo acima, mas tambem não deu certo... printava repetido ainda.
Gostaria da ajuda de vocês ! Valeu.

Edit:

Segue imagem.. No final quando mudar de filial de 1 para 2 e 2 para 3, assim sucessivamente, printar Total por Filial, resume-se nisso ! Pois da forma que estou fazendo, está sendo printado depois de todo resultado por vendedor. Várias vezes.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se vem tudo em um select só, você pode tentar algo assim:

```
$filialAnterior = -1;
for/while/foreach (o que vc usar para o loop){
     if($filialAnterior === $dadosConsulta['numero_filial']){
        // escreve dados
        // conta total da filial
     }else{
        // mudou filial
        // escreve total da filial
        // abre cabeçalho da nova filial
        // zera total da filial
        $filialAnterior =  $dadosConsulta['numero_filial'];
     }
}
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, então... Eu já estou fazendo um loop dentro do loop, o problema é que está vindo os dados assim, exemplo : ( Loja 1, Loja 1, Loja 1, Loja 2, Loja 2, Loja 2, Loja 3 , Loja 3 , Loja 3 e assim por diante ), então se eu comparar filial com filial, ele vai repetir as filiais da mesma forma.

Comment: Seriam 3 níveis? Nível 1: Loja, Nível 2: Filial, Nível 3: Produtos? Seriam 3 loops?

Comment: Sim, acredito que com 3 loops funcionaria (atualizei minha resposta).

Comment: Me avisa se deu certo ok?

Comment: Allan Andrade, tenho uma consulta que traz todos os dados que preciso, e na frente de onde é esses dados ( que filial ), então assim, vem tudo em uma consulta só ! Vou tentar adicionar imagens

Comment: Dá uma olhada na ideia que postei na resposta acima.

Comment: Mas os 3 loops porque ? Sendo que está tudo dentro de 1 array, que é o resultado da consulta. Loja e Filial é a mesma coisa, ou seja, seria 2 loops.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29158/discussion-between-allan-andrade-and-edson-rodrigues).

Comment: Ok ! Te mandei mensagem lá.

Comment: Allan Andrade, obrigado pela ajuda até agora ! Então, até a parte de só mostrar o nome da filial só uma vez deu certo... agora está faltando apenas o resultado POR FILIAL... Este vem de outra pesquisa, ou se tiver outra forma de mostrar esse resultado por filial, beleza também...

Comment: O resultado por filial está sendo impresso apenas da segunda filial em diante... sendo que o valor da primeira filial, está sendo impresso na segunda filial, e da segunda, na terceira e assim por diante.  Estive tentando resolver, mas não deu certo.